# Find column number in excel based on header names using formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a table in excel with the following 2 header row layout:

```
    A      B      C      D      E      F      G      H      I
1 qtr01, qtr02, qtr03, qtr04, qtr01, qtr02, qtr03, qtr04, qtr01
2 2013,  2013,  2013,  2013,  2012,  2012,  2012,  2012,  2015
```

How do I find the column number that matches `qtr02` and `2012` (ie. col number 6) using a formula?

Note: the columns and rows are dynamic within a range. For example, the row that contains "qtr" info may be moved from row 1 to 3 and the headers that match qtr02 and 2012 may be shifted to column G from column F due to an insert of a new column record. This dynamic change depends on the source file received.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “…the row that contains "qtr" info may be moved from row 1 to 3 …”.

Answer (score 1):

To get the column number, use

```
=MATCH(1, (1:1="qtr02")*(2:2=2012), 0)
```

This is an “array formula”, so, after you type it,
you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

- `1:1` refers to all of row `1`. 
  If you’d prefer, you can use `A1:I1` to refer to just the cells that have data.
- `(1:1="qtr02")` looks for `qtr02` in row `1`
  (or the designated cells, as appropriate)
  and constructs a Boolean array of the results. 
  In this case, the array is
  `{FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE}`
  because the second and sixth columns contain `qtr02`.
- Likewise, `(2:2=2012)` creates an array of where the `2012`s are in row `2`:
  namely, `{FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE}`.
- `*`, of course, is multiplication. 
  Since this is an arithmetic operator, it converts its operands to numbers:
  `FALSE` → `0` and `TRUE` → `1`. 
  It then multiplies the two arrays pairwise. 
  This results in a `1` in each position
  where each of the operand arrays has a `1` (`TRUE`) and `0` elsewhere —
  in other words, the columns where both conditions are true. 
  This is equivalent to a logical **AND** function. 
  Excel has a function called `AND()` that does the exact same thing,
  but, unfortunately, it doesn’t work on arrays.  Using `*` is a kludgy trick
  to get around this limitation in the `AND()` function.
- And then, of course, `MATCH(1, array, 0)` finds
  the first element in the array that contains a `1`.